# Xamarin Android Debugging errors

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am repeating a question posed on Xamarin forums by another user as there has been no solution (http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/37139/debug-chaos). Since the update to Xamarin at the start of April.

I'm facing very strange debugging errors using Xamarin Studio.

1)  Set a breakpoint in the IDE and it stops at the breakpoint with a nullreferenceexception, even when the breakpoint is set on a curly bracket of a function.

2) Move the breakpoint by 1 line and the nullreferenceexception will occur there instead.

I have tried to enable/disable fast deploy and mono shared runtime without changes, and fully reinstalled Xamarin Android and Xamarin Studio.

Any ideas? It's very frustrating to not be able to debug.

Update: Xamarin Studio v5.8.2, Xamarin.Android v4.20.0.37, Nexus 7 (2013) running Android 5.0.2

[image: Set the breakpoint here it results in a nullreferenceexception]

[image: Move the breakpoint down one line and it results in a nullreferenceexception there instead]

Comment: What platform? Does it happen all the time? If not, please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing the problem.

Comment: Xamarin.Android. Debugging any code, my own or Xamarin sample code on a 2013 Nexus 7 running Android 5.0.2. Set a breakpoint and it causes a nullreferenceexception. This happens every time wherever the breakpoint is set. If I run in release mode there is no problem.

Comment: This could be an issue with your profile settings. Check your compiler flags and linker settings for non release mode (Debug I assume?) Some of the settings available are not compatible with debugging. AOT and LLVM are not compatible settings for Debugging for example.

Comment: Does it happen in other devices or on emulator ?

Answer (score 0):

it is a related to drawable images problem, please do try it that remove image from layout file and then run application as same configure it will be run successfully.
this type of problem i face at staring but now i have the solution to how to handle it.
setting android images and icon is perfect hierarchy which is mention below images and also update your SDK.

[image]